# Can't call system with white space in parameter

Tags: c, batch-file, system, whitespace

I'm trying to make this system call work. **it works in case there is no space in address**, but it doesn't work if there's a space in address...

this call copies a file from one place to another.

how to escape space in this code properly?

```
char buffer[300];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "copy %s\\%s %s", AssistPath, apiFileName, path);
system(buffer);
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/twistylittlepassagesallalike/archive/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-arguments-the-wrong-way.aspx

Comment: @Dummy00001, I don't have time to read all that, maybe you could apply it to my code?? If you already know the correct method and is interested in helping me...

Comment: Post what the _code_ sees as the values of `AssistPath, apiFileName, path` with `printf("AssistPath:[%s], apiFileName:[%s], path:[%s]\n", AssistPath, apiFileName, path)` which uses `[]` to help identify the true beginning/end of the strings.  Suspect additional issues with your variable assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Space is matter? Then why don't you try this code?

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "copy \"%s\\%s\" \"%s\"", AssistPath, apiFileName, path);
```

Comment: @ufosecret Can you show us your `AssistPath`, `apiFileName` and `path` of test case?

Comment: D:\tt t\assist\api.dll D:\new

Comment: first comes assistpath + filename then new path

Comment: @ufosecret Do you mean `AssistPath = "D:\\tt"`, `apiFileName = "t\\assist\\api.dll"` and `path = "D:\new"`? then they doesn't have space, do they?

Comment: assistpath = `D:\tt t\assist`, filename = `api.dll`, path = `D:\new`, (note the space in the assistpath, between tt and t)

Comment: @ufosecret then chances are that the problem is a bit complicated. Can you show us [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your files(e.g. api.dll) in order to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Right after the snprintf call, add `printf("buffer = %s\n",buffer);` and see what the output is.  That should reveal the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use quotes around the things that may have spaces

```
"copy \"%s\\%s\" \"%s\""
```